# Display custom information according to NavigationLink Text Swift, Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code to get fields "spty" with autoID from collection "specialities":

```
struct Spty: Identifiable{
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var spty: String

}

 class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{


@Published var specialities = [Spty]()

func fetchData(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
       guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return }
        self.specialities = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Spty in
          let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let spty = data["spty"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return Spty(spty: spty)
        }
    }
}
}
```

They are displayed by using ForEach:

```
    @StateObject var sptyModel = SptyViewModel()


    ForEach(sptyModel.specialities){ spty in

           NavigationLink(destination: More()) {
                    
               Text(spty.spty).foregroundColor(.black)
```

As in the code, each `Text(spty.spty)` is a NavigationLink, so what I want is to display different information according to the Text that I pressed.

Im currently working on this getDocuments:

```
 struct Testtt: Identifiable{

   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String

 }


class TesteViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject{

   @StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   @Published var testsss = [Testtt]()
   @Published var sptyModel = SptyViewModel()
   @Published var SptyNameee = [Spty]()


  func testeApp(){

    db.collection("Test").whereField("Los Angeles", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return }
        self.testsss = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Testtt in
           let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let name = data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return Testtt(name: name)
        }
    }
    
}

}
```

- ignore `.whereField`

What I've been thinking is that to answer this question I need to relate `collection()` in testeApp() with `spty.spty` , but didn't managed to do it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

[image: image 1]
[image: 2]
[image: image 3]

[![2
][4]][4]

To clarify my question I added screenshots on how Im currently managing the data:

I get 3 NavLinks in `Home View` accordion to collection "specialities" and the code given above: `Cardiologista`, `Cirurgião Geral` and `Oftalmoloista`

Then, if I press any of the NavLinks, I got to `More` View

There, what I want is: if the user presses `Cardiologista`, the name "Mateus Neves" will appear for him. But, I he presses `Oftalmologista`, the name "Vitor Souza" will appear.

Comment: The question is pretty vague and more importantly, what's preventing you from *Display custom information according to NavigationLink*? In other words, the user clicks or taps a nav link, you get the associated string and then take action based on that string. It's not clear what querying the `Test` collection for `Los Angeles` has to do with that.

Comment: Hey @Jay, thanks for replying. I must haven't chosen the right words, so I will  just add photos on how to information is being stored (some of then are you Portuguese, but this must not interfere in understanding. Quick note: I changed the auto ID in "specialities" collection for the field value, it didn't do any changes and I think it may facilitate solving the problem.

Comment: So if a user chooses *Cardiologista* why don't you read in that collection, iterating over the child documents to populate your tableview Datasource and then display the doctors names in the table?

Comment: Im sorry, Im new to Swift and didn't quite understand what you are saying. I would be grateful if you could just show my a sketch

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. From what I understand, you want the user to click on a collection of Cardiologists and then display the doctors names based on the documents that are in that collection, right?

Comment: @Jay, I want that, if the users click on any field inside collection “specialities” (eg: Cardiologist), he will get the information stored collection “SpecialityClicked” (eg: collection “cardiologist”)

Comment: @Jay, as an example, I can give you AppStore . If you click “Top Paid Apps”, X apps will be displayed. If you click on “Top Free Apps”, Y apps will be displayed.

Comment: @Jay I’m open minded for solutions related to storing data in Firestore that you think is better than the way I’m storing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to attempt address a comment in the question first, which may lead to the answer.

> If you click “Top Paid Apps”, X apps will be displayed. If you click
> on “Top Free Apps”, Y apps will be displayed

Here's a structure that supports that UI

```
allApps (a collection)
   app_0 (a document)
     app_type = "Free"
   app_1
     app_type = "Paid"
```

As you can see, if a user clicks on Free apps, a query is run against Firestore for all documents where `app_type isEqual(to: "Free")`

So then let's expand on that. Lets take specialty types and store them in a collection - this would be the list presented to the user that can select from

```
specialties
   type_0
      name: "Cardiologist"
   type_1
      name: "General"
   type_2
      name: "Anesthesiologist"
```

then the doctors would be stored in a separate collection

```
doctors
   doctor_0
      name: "Dr. Smith"
      type: "type_0"
   doctor_1
      name: "Dr. Jones"
      type: "type_1"
   doctor_2
      name: "Dr. Jenkins"
      type: "type_2"
```

So when the user clicks on Cardiologist in the list, you know that's type_0 and then query the doctors node for all documents where `type isEqual(to: "type_0")` which returns Dr. Smith.

Note

Make sure you map the documents into an object in code that will hold both the type (the documentId) as the name so you can use that as a tableView datasouce.

```
class MyType {
   var type = "" //the firestore documentId
   var name = ""
}

var myTableViewDataSourceArrayOfTypes = [MyType]() //the tableView datasource
```

Comment: Is there a limit of documents inside of a collection in Firestore? Because, based on this method of storing the data, I will have one collection for all the doctors of all specialities, instead of one collection for each speciality

Comment: Actually, after trying to implement this code, Im stuck with a problem.                       db.collection("doctors").whereField("type", isEqualTo: "Cardiologista").getDocuments { If I assign it manually, it works fine. But how to assign it "subjectively"?. By using it like this, in all the specialities in the list I get the same name. Th func where its at is the same testApp()  in the question, just changed whereField

Comment: @MateusNeves There is no limit to documents in a collection. Having a collection of doctors of all specialties is really what you want to do - looking at the question theres no reason to break it out since you can query for what you need within that collection. As far as assigning it `subjectively`, can you clarify? Remember, I 'disconnected' the actual string from the search;  instead of searching for `Cardiologist`, search for `type_0`. This will enable easy support for other languages since the search is tied to the type, not the actual text.

Comment: Just did the change, thank you. What I mean from from subjectively is that: according to whereField("type", isEqualTo: "type_0") I'll only get the documents that have type : "type_0", even if I click in the the other speciality (such as "type_1").

Comment: Based on the current code, even if I click on "SomeSpeciality" that is stored in a document "type_1" inside collection "specialities", I'll get the same text stored in collection "doctors", document "doctor_0", type : "type_0"

Comment: I think you're missing a couple of things. Look at my answer. See where there's a `specialties` collection? You would load the documents in that node and populate an objects in code with BOTH the type and the name. The names are what's displayed in the tableView. When the user clicks on row 0 (for example) in the tableView - that corresponds to row 0 in your dataSource array. Get the object at row 0, so then you know the type (type_0, type_1 etc) and then assemble your query based on the type. Or click row 1 you would get object at row 1 with a type of: type_1 and use that in the query.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thank you so much for all the effort!